# protobuf Kafka consumer with multiple message types

Tags: python, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-schema-registry

I'm using confluent kafka python client to create a protobuf consumer, in the config, it specifies `value.deserializer` with a message type:

```
    protobuf_deserializer = ProtobufDeserializer(newTopic_pb2.Foo)
    string_deserializer = StringDeserializer('utf_8')

    consumer_conf = {'bootstrap.servers': config['bootstrap_servers'],
                     'key.deserializer': string_deserializer,
                     'value.deserializer': protobuf_deserializer,
                     'group.id': config['group'],
                     'auto.offset.reset': "earliest"}

    consumer = DeserializingConsumer(consumer_conf)
    consumer.subscribe('topic1')
```

newTopic.proto looks like:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Foo {
    string f1 = 1;
}
```

Now if I want to add another message type in the proto,

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Foo {
    string f1 = 1;
}


message Bar {
    int32 id = 1;
}
```

Do I have to create a new consumer all together?
Any way I can use the same consumer instance to process the message?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having more than one consumer per application

Comment: @OneCricketeer I used to use the avroconsumer, which subscribes to a list topic, thought doing the same

Comment: `consumer.subscribe` takes multiple topics as a list...

Comment: but it won't work if consumer subscribes to multiple topics with different protobuf schemas, since we have to specify the `value.deserializer` to be a single message in proto definition

Comment: Okay, then like I said, multiple consumers shouldn't be a problem

Comment: just want to make sure, thanks!